# How can I get Windows 10 to stop high jacking the physical mute button of my bluetooth headset?

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth

I have a BT headset with a dedicated mute button.

When I was using it wtih macOS or with my phone, the mute button on the headset mutes the headset and only the headset. It does not interact with computer or the phone.

But when I pair the headset with my Windows computer, the physical mute button doesn't do anything.

I use it with video conferencing products like Google Meet, Zoom, WebEx and BJM but those aren't the culprit issue.

- When paired with my phone the headset mute button mutes just the headset. I can also mute from the phone to be essentially double muted.
- When paired with macOS the headset mute button mutes just the headset. I can also mute from the computer to be essentially double muted.
- When paired with Windows 10, the headset mute button does nothing. I can only mute from the computer.

Is there anyway to get Windows 10 to stop highjacking my headset's mute button?

Comment: Which headset is it? That might help with any diagnosis

Comment: Some cheap one from Amazon: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B09FL1K5HD/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o07_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1. Do you think it is something specific to the headset and not Windows?